# Why is JavaScript logging it "0"?

Tags: javascript

This code logs the output to be zero. Output should be 6.

```js
function sum(a,b){
  r=a+b;
  return r; 
}

r=sum(2,9);
r1=sum(1,4);
diff=r-r1;

console.log(diff);
```

Comment: Where are you declaring r? It looks like it's probably out of the scope of the function so when you call sum it overwrites r. Thus you're subtracting the same value from itself and getting 0.

Comment: You need to declare all your `r` variables, otherwise when doing your second `sum` call `r`is overwritten to `r = 5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've to use `var` keyword when you declare the `r` variable localy inside the fucntion else you'll have a *scope conflict* and the `r` inside the function will be declared globaly and considered as the same variable with the `r` variable outside the function :

```
function sum(a,b){
    var r=a+b;
    return r; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function sum(a,b){
    var r=a+b;
    return r; 
}

r=sum(2,9);
r1=sum(1,4);
diff=r-r1;

console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `var` when declaring variables. By not using `var` you are implicitly creating global variables.

```
function sum(a,b){
    r=a+b; // This ends up being a reference to the same `r` as below
    return r; 
}

r=sum(2,9); // This creates a global variable called r and sets it to 11
r1=sum(1,4); // This sets global `r` to 5 (because of the r=a+b in sum()
diff=r-r1; // 5 - 5 is 0
console.log(diff);
```

Instead do this:

```
function sum(a,b){
    var r=a+b; // Now this r is local to the sum() function
    return r; 
}

var r=sum(2,9); // Now this r is local to whatever scope you are in
var r1=sum(1,4);
var diff=r-r1;
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 2):

`r` is referred to both inside and outside of `sum`. It is then not a local variable, but exists outside of the function. Any call to `sum` will overwrite the previous value of `r`.

`r1=sum(1,4);` in particular will set both `r` and `r1` to `5`, and so `diff` will then be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not declared the variable r inside the

function with var keyword.So,it is in global scope.

When you are doing this r1=sum(1,4),the value of r is overridden to

5 and the value of r1 is also 5.So the difference of r-r1 turns

out to be 0.

To avoid this,you can use var keyword to declare r inside the function.

```
function sum(a,b){
    var r=a+b;
    return r; 
}

r=sum(2,9);
r1=sum(1,4);
diff=r-r1;

console.log(diff);
```

This will help.